# Python Insert list items in a for loop structure

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

New to Python. I need to insert an item for a list in a for loop structure this way:

- Item-1: List-Item-1
- Item-2: List-Item-2
- Item-n: List-Item-n

Here is my code:

```
mylist = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"]

length = len(mylist)
print length
length += 1
print length

for i in range(1, length):
    print " item %d:" % i
```

I just can figure it out. I'm able to print the list item or the item number separated but I can't get them together

Any Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate(..)` for that:

```
for i,item in enumerate(mylist,1):
    print " item-%d: %s" %(i,item)
```

or even shorter:

```
for tup in enumerate(mylist,1):
    print " item-%d: %s" %tup
```

The `1` in `enumerate(..)` means you start counting at `1`. `enumerate(..)` will produce a *enumerable* of tuples containing the index (here `i`) and the element (here `item`). In the `for` loop we use *sequence unpacking* to unpack them and print the properly:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mylist = ["uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"]
>>> for i,item in enumerate(mylist,1):
...     print " item-%d: %s" %(i,item)
... 
 item-1: uno
 item-2: dos
 item-3: tres
 item-4: cuatro
```